# Possible to use an istream with memcpy

Tags: c++, boost, stream, buffer

I am working on a C++ application that uses a library that is written in C (StormLib). The library has a function to read a file to a `void* buffer`(I am guessing a `char[]`). To which I would like to send to a different library to be processed. Hopefully it can be done with something like `boost::iostreams::stream_buffer` or `boost::asio::streambuf` to store the file as to be read by whatever method needs.

I have tried simply passing in a istream (that has a `boost::asio::streambuf` open) to the function and it gives me a BADACCESS as it tried to execute

`memcpy((theFile),(myiStream),(full size of the file))`

I would basically like a sort of "bag of bits" object that can be easily moved to different methods for conversion of the data in a structured fashion but I do not know how I should implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you want to do with the data once you have it back in C++?  If you just want the raw data, then you could (for example) just create a `std::vector<char>`, `resize` so it's big enough to hold all the data<sup>*</sup>, and then pass a pointer to its first element.

---

<sub>* How you determine "big enough" is a different question...</sub>

Comment: I would like to hand it off to a library to convert the data using ImageMagick or FFMPEG (depending on the file type) and then write the result to a file. 
The size of the object could be from 3KB to 500MB+

Comment: @user1939612: It sounds like you just want something to hold arbitrary data.  So something like `std::vector` would do the trick.

Comment: It seems to work, did this specifically for future reference with StormLib

`std::vector<char> fileBuffer;`
 `fileBuffer.resize(SFileGetFileSize(fileHandle, NULL));`
 `HANDLE fileHandle;`
       `if (!SFileReadFile(fileHandle, &fileBuffer[0], SFileGetFileSize(fileHandle, NULL), NULL, NULL))`
        `{`
            `throw "failed to read file to memory";`
       `}`

Comment: @user1939612 dont throw X if X is not std::exception or derived from std::Exception :P

Comment: NoSenseEtAl - Oops I posted the snippet up too fast.
@OliCharlesworth - How do I delete the vector?

Comment: @user1939612: You don't need to, as you didn't dynamically declare it.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth If I do `std::vector<char> *name = function that returns std::vector<char>` would require  a delete correct? If so how?

Comment: @user1939612: As normal: `delete name;`.  But generally speaking, dynamically creating containers is a bit weird in C++.